# El form no se expande cuando se le pone max-width

Tags: html, css, css3, web

Lo que quiero es que el `form` ocupe el 70% de la pantalla, pero cuando le pongo `max-width: 70%`, este se desconfigura.

Lo que tengo en HTML es esto:

```css
.contact-wrapper {
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
}
 
  ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  .logon {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 3em;
  }
  
  .logon span {
    color: #B70E21;
  }
  
  .contact-wrapper {
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
  }
  
  .contact-wrapper > * {
    padding: 1em;
  }
  
  .contact-form {
    background: #222222;
    width: 1000px;
  }
  
  .contact-form form {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }
  
  .contact-form form label {
    display: block;
  }
  
  .contact-form form p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em;
  }
  
  .contact-form form .block {
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
  }
  
  .contact-form form button,
  .contact-form form input,
  .contact-form form textarea {
    width: 100%;
    padding: .7em;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    outline: 0;
    color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d63031;
  }
  
  .contact-form form button {
    background: #B70E21;
    border: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 1em;
  }
  
  .contact-form form button:hover,
  .contact-form form button:focus {
    background: #d63031;
    color: #fff;
    transition: background-color 1s ease-out;
    outline: 0;
  }
  
  
  /* CONTACT INFO */
  .contact-info {
    background: #000;
  }
  
  .contact-info h4, .contact-info ul, .contact-info p {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 0 1rem 0;
  }
  
  /* LARGE SIZE */
  @media(min-width: 700px) {
    body {
        padding: 0 0em;
        
    }
    .contact-wrapper {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
    }
    .contact-wrapper > * {
        padding: 2em;
    }
    .contact-info h4,
    .contact-info ul,
    .contact-info p {
        text-align: left;
    }
  }
```

```html
    <div class="contents">

                                
                        
                                <div class="contact-wrapper animated bounceInUp">
                                    <div class="contact-form">
                                        <h3>Formulario de Contacto</h3>
                                        <form action="">
                                            <p>
                                                <label>Nombre y Apellido</label>
                                                <input type="text" name="Nombre"  required>
                                            </p>
                                            <p>
                                                <label>Email</label>
                                                <input type="email" name="email" required>
                                            </p>
                                            <p>
                                                <label>Número de Teléfono</label>
                                                <input type="tel" name="Teléfono" required>
                                            </p>
                                            <p>
                                                <label>Asunto</label>
                                                <input type="text" name="Asunto" required>
                                            </p>
                                            <p class="block">
                                               <label>Mensaje</label> 
                                                <textarea name="Mensaje" rows="3" required></textarea>
                                            </p>
                                            <p class="block">
                                                <button>
                                                    Enviar
                                                </button>
                                            </p>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="contact-info">
                                        <iframe 
                                    src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3405.7801759309814!2d-64.2229648851589!3d-31.39262430224355!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x943298c23bd9ea5f%3A0x9fb67e9fefbbf13e!2sRufino%20Cuervo%201085%2C%20C%C3%B3rdoba!5e0!3m2!1ses-419!2sar!4v1630007385428!5m2!1ses-419!2sar"
                                    width="380" height="400" style="border:0; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy"></iframe>
                                    <h4 style="font-size: 15px; color: gray; margin: 1px 0px 0px 1px; ">Número de Teléfono: +54-(351) 3953137/+54-(351) 6802047 </h4>
                                    <h4 style="font-size: 15px; color: gray; margin: 1px 0px 0px 1px;">Email: <a href="mailto:estudio@aclif.com.ar">estudio@aclif.com.ar</a>/<a href="mailto:laura@aclif.com.ar"> laura@aclif.com.ar</a></h4>
                                </div>
                                </div>
```

Lo que yo quisiera es que aparezca más grande, como el 70% de la pantalla. Me queda así:
[image: Como me quedó el form]

Answer (score 4):

Para que los elementos se puedan ajustar correctamente te sugiero utilizar width:100%.

He realizado algunos cambios en la clase de estilos .contact-form, se agrego la clase .contents y agregue width: 100% al iframe.

```css
.contact-wrapper {
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
}
 
  ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  .logon {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 3em;
  }
  
  .logon span {
    color: #B70E21;
  }
  
  .contact-wrapper {
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
  }
  
  .contact-wrapper > * {
    padding: 1em;
  }
  
  .contact-form {
    background: #222222;
    width: 90%;
  }
  
  .contact-form form {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }
  
  .contact-form form label {
    display: block;
  }
  
  .contact-form form p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em;
  }
  
  .contact-form form .block {
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
  }
  
  .contact-form form button,
  .contact-form form input,
  .contact-form form textarea {
    width: 100%;
    padding: .7em;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    outline: 0;
    color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d63031;
  }
  
  .contact-form form button {
    background: #B70E21;
    border: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 1em;
  }
  
  .contact-form form button:hover,
  .contact-form form button:focus {
    background: #d63031;
    color: #fff;
    transition: background-color 1s ease-out;
    outline: 0;
  }
  
  
  /* CONTACT INFO */
  .contact-info {
    background: #000;
        width: 90%;
  }
  
  .contact-info h4, .contact-info ul, .contact-info p {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 0 1rem 0;
  }
  
  /* LARGE SIZE */
  @media(min-width: 700px) {
    body {
        padding: 0 0em;
        
    }
    .contact-wrapper {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
    }
    .contact-wrapper > * {
        padding: 2em;
    }
    .contact-info h4,
    .contact-info ul,
    .contact-info p {
        text-align: left;
    }
  }
  
    .contents{
              margin-left: 15%;
            margin-right: 15%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="contents">

                                
                        
                                <div class="contact-wrapper animated bounceInUp">
                                    <div class="contact-form">
                                        <h3>Formulario de Contacto</h3>
                                        <form action="">
                                            <p>
                                                <label>Nombre y Apellido</label>
                                                <input type="text" name="Nombre"  required>
                                            </p>
                                            <p>
                                                <label>Email</label>
                                                <input type="email" name="email" required>
                                            </p>
                                            <p>
                                                <label>Número de Teléfono</label>
                                                <input type="tel" name="Teléfono" required>
                                            </p>
                                            <p>
                                                <label>Asunto</label>
                                                <input type="text" name="Asunto" required>
                                            </p>
                                            <p class="block">
                                               <label>Mensaje</label> 
                                                <textarea name="Mensaje" rows="3" required></textarea>
                                            </p>
                                            <p class="block">
                                                <button>
                                                    Enviar
                                                </button>
                                            </p>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="contact-info">
                                        <iframe 
                                    src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3405.7801759309814!2d-64.2229648851589!3d-31.39262430224355!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x943298c23bd9ea5f%3A0x9fb67e9fefbbf13e!2sRufino%20Cuervo%201085%2C%20C%C3%B3rdoba!5e0!3m2!1ses-419!2sar!4v1630007385428!5m2!1ses-419!2sar"
                                    width="100%" height="400" style="border:0; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy"></iframe>
                                    <h4 style="font-size: 15px; color: gray; margin: 1px 0px 0px 1px; ">Número de Teléfono: +54-(351) 3953137/+54-(351) 6802047 </h4>
                                    <h4 style="font-size: 15px; color: gray; margin: 1px 0px 0px 1px;">Email: <a href="mailto:estudio@aclif.com.ar">estudio@aclif.com.ar</a>/<a href="mailto:laura@aclif.com.ar"> laura@aclif.com.ar</a></h4>
                                </div>
                                </div>
```

Comment: Perfecto, pero sigue igual. No sé porqué será...

Comment: Revisa la clase "contents" en tu form,  esa clase de estilo yo la agregue por que tu no la anexaste al código

Comment: Lo tengo con width:70%, pero no sé porqué no lo refleja así

Answer (score 2):

Te muestro una forma de solucionarlo. Lo que hice basicamente en tu css fue añadir una clase mas contents. Donde coloque el 70% que deseabas y ademas un margin auto para centrarlo.

```
.contents{
  width: 70%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
    }
    .contact-wrapper {
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
}
 
  ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  .logon {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 3em;
  }
  
  .logon span {
    color: #B70E21;
  }
  
  .contact-wrapper {
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
  }
  
  .contact-wrapper > * {
    padding: 1em;
  }
```

además en tu contacto-form, coloque un width 1fr que sería que tome todo el espacio que tenga disponible, en este caso sería el 70% de toda la pantalla disponible.

```
  .contact-form {
    background: #222222;
    width: 1fr;
    
  }
  
  .contact-form form {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }
  
  .contact-form form label {
    display: block;
  }
  
  .contact-form form p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em;
  }
  
  .contact-form form .block {
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
  }
  
  .contact-form form button,
  .contact-form form input,
  .contact-form form textarea {
    width: 100%;
    padding: .7em;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    outline: 0;
    color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d63031;
  }
  
  .contact-form form button {
    background: #B70E21;
    border: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 1em;
  }
  
  .contact-form form button:hover,
  .contact-form form button:focus {
    background: #d63031;
    color: #fff;
    transition: background-color 1s ease-out;
    outline: 0;
  }
  
  
  /* CONTACT INFO */
  .contact-info {
    background: #000;
    max-width: ;
  }
  
  .contact-info h4, .contact-info ul, .contact-info p {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 0 1rem 0;
  }
  
  /* LARGE SIZE */
  @media(min-width: 700px) {
    body {
        padding: 0 0em;
        
    }
    .contact-wrapper {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
    }
    .contact-wrapper > * {
        padding: 2em;
    }
    .contact-info h4,
    .contact-info ul,
    .contact-info p {
        text-align: left;
    }
  }
```

Espero ser de ayuda

Comment: Perfecto! Lo único es que no puedo interactuar con el mapa...

Comment: A qué te refieres con interactuar exactamente? Ayúdame a comprenderte mejor, por favor

Comment: Hice una mejora necesaria en contents, por favor prueba